# passing JSON as a query string in the URL

Tags: c#, json, typescript, .net-core

I need to send a JSON file as a query string in a unique URI that is provided by the user. I am sending the JSON data from my angular application to .net core application like so:

```
 UploadData(vData:DataModel){
    const httpOptions = { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }) };
    return  this.http.post<DataModel>(ROOT_URL, vData, httpOptions);
   }
```

In my .net core 3.1 application, I am receiving the data like this:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult<string> Post(Identitydata model)
        {

        }
```

Since my data is already in JSON, I think, I don't need to format the data. How can I send this data to the client as a querystring:

any help will be appreciated

Comment: Is it a requirement to send data in uri and not body?

Comment: yes, i need to send the data to Experian and their requirement is to send the data in UR. It will be a unique URI

Comment: I doubt they will have this limitation. You’ll need to url encode the json plus you can run into limitation on length. I think they should be able to accept the json in body, I would confirm that requirement. If so you can add [FromBody] attribute in your action and do a ajax post to that.

Comment: Ok, i will find out on Monday

Comment: do you have any example of adding frombody attribute in the action

Comment: Check out this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Thanks, I read the article. This will solve the issue that I am having.